# How to get and set the current web page scroll position?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get and set the current web page scroll position?

I have a long form which needs to be refreshed based on user actions/input.  When this happens, the page resets to the very top, which is annoying to the users, because they have to scroll back down to the point they were at.

If I could capture the current scroll position (in a hidden input) before the page reloads, I could then set it back after it reloads.

Comment: Isn't an AJAX-driven form not a better way to prevent those effects (and of course provide a fallback in case XHR is unavailable)? Page reloads will have the page to jump to the top and back again, a quirk that can be annoying.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You're looking for the `document.documentElement.scrollTop` property.

Comment: thanks, I found this: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/javascript-from-scratch/6 and modified the `getScrollingPosition()` to store the values in hidden variables. Then in the html of the refreshed page I use `<body onLoad="window.scrollTo(x,y)`, where x and y are those from the hidden values values!

Comment: I'm finding, on Chrome on Ubuntu at least, that `document.documentElement.scrollTop` is always returning 0. `document.body.scrollTop`, however, seems to work. One Firefox on Ubuntu, on the other hand, the reverse is true - you get 0 with `body` and the correct amount with `documentElement`. Any idea what gives?

Comment: This answer is not accurate as the `scrollTop` property doesn't work on all browsers. Check `window.pageXOffset` and `window.pageYOffset` for better results.

Answer (score 193):

The currently accepted answer is incorrect - `document.documentElement.scrollTop` always returns 0 on Chrome. This is because WebKit uses `body` for keeping track of scrolling, whereas Firefox and IE use `html`.

To get the current position, you want:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
```

You can set the current position to 1000px down the page like so:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = 1000;
```

Or, using jQuery (animate it while you're at it!):

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "1000px" });
```

Comment: gyo's answer, suggesting `window.pageYOffset` is cleaner if you're using `window.scrollBy()` or `window.scrollTo()` methods.

Answer (score 66):

Update 2021: browsers inconsistencies with `scrollTop` seem to have disappeared.

There are some inconsistencies in how browsers expose the current window scrolling coordinates. **Google Chrome** on **Mac** and **iOS** seems to always return `0` when using `document.documentElement.scrollTop` or jQuery's `$(window).scrollTop()`.

However, it works consistently with:

```
// horizontal scrolling amount
window.pageXOffset

// vertical scrolling amount
window.pageYOffset
```

Comment: I've noticed it too, is it a bug on Mac and iOS?

Comment: @AlexanderKim I think it might be related to how certain CSS rules (like overflow) are interpreted, and it has been reported to work if checking scrollTop on both the body and html elements. However, to avoid testing and debugging, I always rely on the safe and consistent pageXOffset/pageYOffset.

Answer (score 5):

I went with the HTML5 local storage solution...  All my links call a function which sets this before changing window.location:

```
localStorage.topper = document.body.scrollTop;
```

and each page has this in the body's onLoad:

```
  if(localStorage.topper > 0){ 
    window.scrollTo(0,localStorage.topper);
  }
```

Comment: It would be more elegant to use setItem() and getItem() of localStorage and instead back up the scroll position at each link click, store it once when leaving the page: window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { localStorage.setItem("scrolly", document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop); });

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays it seems like the get is working with: `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY`. This could be an alternative way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var stop = true;
  addEventListener('drag', (event) => {
    if (event.clientY < 150) {
      stop = false;
      scroll(-1)
    }
    if (event.clientY > ($(window).height() - 150)) {
      stop = false;
      scroll(1)
    }
    if (document.body.getBoundingClientRect().y === 0){
      stop = true;
    }
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
      stop = true;
    }
  });
  addEventListener('dragend', (event) => {
    stop = true;
  });

  var scroll = function (step) {
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollY + step);
    if (!stop) {
      setTimeout(function () { scroll(step) }, 20);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Best solution ever!!!

Comment: You need to explain the solution for better understandability.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current scroll position with `window.scrollY`/scrollX, store it temporarily in browser storage and on refresh, access it to reset page scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the px value of scroll from top

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

Answer (score -1):

Now you can also use `window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });` instead of using that jQuery solution above for the animation. Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31494331)