# offsetParent not usable for position calculation for HTML-elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is how I'm calculating the correct position of an element, which should work also for scrolled position.

```
var element = $('#target');
console.log(getPosition(element));

getPosition = function (element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while (element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
};
```

But I get the error `'SVGElement.offsetLeft' is deprecated and will be removed in M50, around April 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5724912467574784 for more details.`

It seems to me that I used `offsetXY` in a wrong way...

Comment: Use `getBoundingClientRect()` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Offset Position of SVG Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040685/finding-offset-position-of-svg-element)