# auto-scroll to same place before leaving the page?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Is there a way to automatically scroll to the same place in the page that was before leaving it?

for example - the client is in the middle of the page -> then goes to google -> and when he entered the page again the page will be scrolled to the previous position.

I found this [HTML5 local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15458166/2216190) but I don't know if it usable in this case of leaving the page completely...

Comment: Local storage will persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what you need yes. LocalStorage keeps the `keys` that you store in the user's computer, so even if the browser is closed the `key`is there when you open the site again.

You can find more info on 'How to use it' [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)