# Ho to make a navbar that fades in when the page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, css, html

I made a navigation bar with a background that changes color from transparent to translucent black when the user scrolls down. My problem is I can't get it to change back to transparent when the user scrolls to the top of the page
here what i have so far

HTML:

```
<nav id="mynav" style="transition: 1.4s ease-in" position:fixed;> <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="Courses.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="Log In">Videos</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Images</a>
  </li>    
</ul></nav>
```

JS:

```
    window.onscroll = navfade;
function navfade(){
    var nbar = document.getElementById("mynav");
    if(nbar.scrollTop < 5){
        nbar.style.background = "rgba(10,10,20,0.45)";
    }else {
        nbar.style.background = "transparent";
    }
}
```

Comment: your `mynav` div is in position fixed, so its `scrollTop` value will never change (i had 0 in my tests, but i can change with your CSS). Your code should work and turn back to transparent, but it doesn't because `nbar.scrollTop < 5` is always true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `navFade` function value of `nbar.scrollTop` is always 0.

Check [How to get and set the current web page scroll position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096863/how-to-get-and-set-the-current-web-page-scroll-position/28488360)

I replaced `nbar.scrollTop` with `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

```js
window.onscroll = navfade;
function navfade(){
    var nbar = document.getElementById("mynav");
   
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop < 5){
        nbar.style.background = "rgba(10,10,20,0.45)";
    }else {
        nbar.style.background = "transparent";
    }
}
```

```html
<nav id="mynav" style="transition: 1.4s ease-in" position:fixed;> <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="Courses.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="Log In">Videos</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Images</a>
  </li>    
</ul></nav>

<div>Fake Content</div>
<div>Fake Content</div>
<div>Fake Content</div>
<div>Fake Content</div>
<div>Fake Content</div>
<div>Fake Content</div>
<div>Fake Content</div>
```