# How to have JS take care of multiple events for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm drawing a blank on how to handle events within Javascript, and want to avoid using a modular function that has the "onclick" within the html  tag. Basically, I want to write a function that will scroll to the section of the page containing that element on click, but I'm drawing a blank on how to do that.

I have a modular function like this:

```
var elmnt = $("#links").on("click", function() {
    elmnt.scrollIntoView;
    console.log;
});
```

Now, I pass the argument on the a href tag, but how do I have JS look for these events and scroll to them? Do I write a function for each link clicked? Is there a better way to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to invoke functions like `console.log()` or `elem.scrollIntoView()`

Comment: You should provide your HTML as well, as your jQuery selector here can only select an individual element, so we can't say how you would do this for multiple and people are just guessing. `<a href="#id">` already does what you want by default, but we can't know if you are using links to `id`s.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few corrections:

1) scrollIntoView is function

2) click callback handler should have reference to element

Check below code.

```
var elmnt = $("#links").on("click", function(ele) {
    ele.scrollIntoView();
    //console.log;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is not for JS to "search for events", but to bind the buttons and destinations using a loop in an init script. Then all you need to do is to define the target of a button with an attribute, and JS will automatically take care of the rest.

<s>Hence, you might wish to make `scrollIntoView()` a global function, and have it accept the element you wish to scroll to as a param, like such.</s>

```
function scrollIntoView(target) {
  // Scroll code here
}
```

For scroll code example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26230989/5637701) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28488360/5637701)

Edit: somethinghere pointed out that scrollIntoView() is actually natively supported, so there is no need to write your own function anymore.

Say you have 3 buttons and 3 destinations in your DOM (I will use `button` in place of `a` for clarity's sake):

```
<button class="button_type_a" type="button">Scroll to destination A</button>
<button class="button_type_a" type="button">Scroll to destination B</button>
<button class="button_type_k" type="button">Scroll to destination C</button>

...

<div id="dest_A">Destination A</div>
<div id="dest_B">Destination B</div>
<div id="dest_C">Destination C</div>
```

First prepare the buttons:

1. Add an arbitrary class (`goto_button`) to indicate the intended action of the button
2. Add an arbitrary attribute (`target`) to indicate their respective destinations

Something like this:

```
<button class="button_type_a goto_button" type="button" target="dest_A">Scroll to destination A</button>
<button class="button_type_a goto_button" type="button" target="dest_B">Scroll to destination B</button>
<button class="button_type_k goto_button" type="button" target="dest_C">Scroll to destination C</button>
```

in which the value of `target` is the `id` of the destination.

Then in your JS, first find all your buttons:

```
var gotoButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("goto_button");
```

Then loop through your buttons, and for each one search and bind to their destination:

```
for (let btn of gotoButtons) {
  let target = btn.getAttribute("target");
  let destination = document.getElementById(target);
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    destination.scrollIntoView();
  });
}
```

Load this JS as an init script for your page and you should be all set.

Comment: `Element.scrollIntoView` is actually a native JS method on an element, so no need to 'define that yourself'. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Comment: @somethinghere thanks. I remember seeing someone writing a custom function for this feature and so I have been doing the same. This is helpful to know. Answer edited accordingly.